# Are some problems undecidable even given an infinite time?

Tags: logic

Are undecidable problems only those that have no algorithm to give a yes or no answer in a finite time or are there problems with no algorithm to give a yes no answer even in an infinite time? (If undecidability means there isn't a yes/no answer over a finite period, doesn't that mean given enough time these problems are  actually decidable?)

If some problems do require an infinite time to be answered can you give examples of these problems?

Comment: Yes, there are logics that are incomplete.

Comment: There are some problems that cannot be solved even with an infinite amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyperarithmetic sets of integers are precisely the ones for which membership in them is decidable algorithmically, with a finite set of instructions, if you are allowed to do an infinite sequence of steps in any positive time interval you want.  (These sets are the effective analogue to the Borel sets.)

A simple example of a hyperarithmetic set which is not recursive is the set of all (codes for) Turing machines which halt, with an empty tape as input.  There are many hyperarithmetic sets that are much more complicated than this one, however.

A good source for this is *Theory of Recursive Functions and Effective Computability*, by Hartley Rogers, Jr.  See Chapter 16 (The Analytical Hierarchy), section 16.5 (Generalized Computability), p. 407 (in the paragraphs under the heading Generalized Machines).

Needless to say, this doesn't make all hyperarithmetic sets decidable.  They're only decidable in this generalized sense in which infinite sequences of algorithmic steps are allowed.

Comment: How does this help with the OP's idea that given enough time undecidable problems become decidable?

Comment: @RobArthan I added a bit to my answer on that (together with a more detailed reference).  As you say, it doesn't turn undecidable sets into decidable ones, but the hyperarithmetic sets are the sets that satisfy a generalization of decidability, using infinitely many steps, along the lines the OP asked about.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, an algorithm must give an answer in a finite time (although that time may be arbitrarily long).

For example: the halting problem is undecidable.  That is, there is no algorithm that, given a Turing machine and its input, decides whether or not the Turing machine given that input will halt.

Now you could just simulate running the Turing machine on that input.  If the simulation halts, you return Yes.   However, there is the possibility that the Turing machine will go on forever without halting.  We can't just say "if it runs forever, return No", precisely because only an answer in a finite time counts as an answer.

Comment: I learned that an algorithm is a finite set of steps which might run forever. Take for(;;) for example.

Comment: An algorithm can run forever, but it does not **give an answer** when it does.

Comment: So we just keep the answer $A$ in the definition even though $A$ is undefined?

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question about what problems could be solved algorithmically if one had infinitely much time available.  See my answer on the hyperarithmetic sets regarding that.